# Fix for jQuery splitter in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, splitter

**Update:**

This issue is with regards to [multiple pane splitter](http://methvin.com/splitter/4psplitter.html) which was working fine in all browsers except IE9. The widths for the right pane children do not resize accordingly upon window resize.

(In the context of my application, I also had to put the right pane split method in a different javascript thread using setTimeout, 0 delay, otherwise the widths/top positions go wild in IE9.)

Comment: the 2-times splitter as a whole is not stable in IE9, re-phrasing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, which was jQuery .browser.msie conditionals used in jQuery splitter plugin.

Answer (score 7):

I had trouble getting the plug-in working until I combined garlon4's solution with another fix required for jQuery 1.6+. Here is what I did:

I added the function:

```
function browser_resize_auto_fired() {
  // Returns true when the browser natively fires the resize 
  // event attached to the panes elements
  return ($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version) < 9));
}
```

Then replaced instances of

```
!$browser.msie
```

with

```
!browser_resize_auto_fired()
```

Finally, to get the plug-in working under jquery 1.6+, I changed this code:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function (e) {
  var top = splitter.offset().top;
  var wh = $(window).height();
  splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
  if (!browser_resize_auto_fired()) splitter.trigger("resize");
}).trigger("resize");
```

to this:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function (e) {
  if (e.target == window) {
    var top = splitter.offset().top;
    var wh = $(window).height();
    splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
    if (!browser_resize_auto_fired()) splitter.trigger("resize");
  }
}).trigger("resize");
```

Here is the full code for the plug-in, containing the fixes:

```
/*
 * jQuery.splitter.js - two-pane splitter window plugin
 *
 * version 1.51 (2009/01/09)
 * version 1.52 (2012/05/08) -- Fixes by Roger Martin
 *  * Added check in window resize event handler to run only when the target is the window. This fixes a breaking
 *    change introduced in jQuery 1.6.
 *  * Added support for IE 9+
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * 
 */

/**
* The splitter() plugin implements a two-pane resizable splitter window.
* The selected elements in the jQuery object are converted to a splitter;
* each selected element should have two child elements, used for the panes
* of the splitter. The plugin adds a third child element for the splitbar.
*
* For more details see: http://methvin.com/splitter/
*
*
* @example $('#MySplitter').splitter();
* @desc Create a vertical splitter with default settings
*
* @example $('#MySplitter').splitter({type: 'h', accessKey: 'M'});
* @desc Create a horizontal splitter resizable via Alt+Shift+M
*
* @name splitter
* @type jQuery
* @param Object options Options for the splitter (not required)
* @cat Plugins/Splitter
* @return jQuery
* @author Dave Methvin (dave.methvin@gmail.com)
*/
 ; (function ($) {

$.fn.splitter = function (args) {
 args = args || {};
 return this.each(function () {
   var zombie;      // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes
   function startSplitMouse(evt) {
     if (opts.outline)
       zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
     panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");  // Safari selects A/B text on a move
     bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
     A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - evt[opts.eventPos];
     $(document)
            .bind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
            .bind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
   }
   function doSplitMouse(evt) {
     var newPos = A._posSplit + evt[opts.eventPos];
     if (opts.outline) {
       newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
       bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
     } else
       resplit(newPos);
   }
   function endSplitMouse(evt) {
     bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
     var newPos = A._posSplit + evt[opts.eventPos];
     if (opts.outline) {
       zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
       resplit(newPos);
     }
     panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");  // let Safari select text again
     $(document)
            .unbind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
            .unbind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
   }
   function resplit(newPos) {
     // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
     newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max,
                Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
     // Resize/position the two panes
     bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];        // bar size may change during dock
     bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
     A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
     B.css(opts.origin, newPos + bar._DA)
            .css(opts.split, splitter._DA - bar._DA - newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
     // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
     if (!browser_resize_auto_fired())
       panes.trigger("resize");
   }
   function dimSum(jq, dims) {
     // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
     var sum = 0;
     for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
       sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
     return sum;
   }
   function browser_resize_auto_fired() {
     // Returns true when the browser natively fires the resize event attached to the panes elements
     return ($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version) < 9));
   }

   // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
   var vh = (args.splitHorizontal ? 'h' : args.splitVertical ? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
   var opts = $.extend({
     activeClass: 'active', // class name for active splitter
     pxPerKey: 8,           // splitter px moved per keypress
     tabIndex: 0,           // tab order indicator
     accessKey: ''          // accessKey for splitbar
   }, {
     v: {                   // Vertical splitters:
       keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "e-resize",
       splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
       type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
       split: "width", pxSplit: "offsetWidth", side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
       fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top", side4: "Bottom"
     },
     h: {                   // Horizontal splitters:
       keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38, cursor: "n-resize",
       splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
       type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
       split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top", side2: "Bottom",
       fixed: "width", pxFixed: "offsetWidth", side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
     }
   }[vh], args);

   // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
   var splitter = $(this).css({ position: "relative" });
   var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
     position: "absolute",          // positioned inside splitter container
     "z-index": "1",                    // splitbar is positioned above
     "-moz-outline-style": "none"   // don't show dotted outline
   });
   var A = $(panes[0]);     // left  or top
   var B = $(panes[1]);     // right or bottom

   // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
   var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
        .attr({ accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass })
        .bind($.browser.opera ? "click" : "focus", function () { this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
        .bind("keydown", function (e) {
          var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
          var dir = key == opts["key" + opts.side1] ? 1 : key == opts["key" + opts.side2] ? -1 : 0;
          if (dir)
            resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit] + dir * opts.pxPerKey, false);
        })
        .bind("blur", function () { bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

   // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
   var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
        .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
        .attr({ "class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on" })
        .css({
          position: "absolute", "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
          "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"
        })
        .bind("mousedown", startSplitMouse);
   // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
   if (/^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")))
     bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

   // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
   bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
   splitter._PBF = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side3 + "Width", "border" + opts.side4 + "Width") : 0;
   splitter._PBA = $.boxModel ? dimSum(splitter, "border" + opts.side1 + "Width", "border" + opts.side2 + "Width") : 0;
   A._pane = opts.side1;
   B._pane = opts.side2;
   $.each([A, B], function () {
     this._min = opts["min" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-" + opts.split);
     this._max = opts["max" + this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-" + opts.split) || 9999;
     this._init = opts["size" + this._pane] === true ?
            parseInt($.curCSS(this[0], opts.split)) : opts["size" + this._pane];
   });

   // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
   var initPos = A._init;
   if (!isNaN(B._init)) // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
     initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
   if (opts.cookie) {
     if (!$.cookie)
       alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
     var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
     if (!isNaN(ckpos))
       initPos = ckpos;
     $(window).bind("unload", function () {
       var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));    // current location of splitbar
       $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {
         expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365,
         path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname
       });
     });
   }
   if (isNaN(initPos))  // King Solomon's algorithm
     initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA) / 2);

   // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
   if (opts.anchorToWindow) {
     // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
     splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
     splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
     $(window).bind("resize", function (e) {
       if (e.target == window) {
         var top = splitter.offset().top;
         var wh = $(window).height();
         splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh - top - splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin) + "px");
         if (!browser_resize_auto_fired()) splitter.trigger("resize");
       }
     }).trigger("resize");
   }
   else if (opts.resizeToWidth && !browser_resize_auto_fired())
     $(window).bind("resize", function () {
       splitter.trigger("resize");
     });

   // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
   splitter.bind("resize", function (e, size) {
     // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't get into a Yo Dawg
     if (e.target != this) return;
     // Determine new width/height of splitter container
     splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
     splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
     // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
     if (splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0) return;
     // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
     resplit(!isNaN(size) ? size : (!(opts.sizeRight || opts.sizeBottom) ? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
            splitter._DA - B[0][opts.pxSplit] - bar._DA));
   }).trigger("resize", [initPos]);
 });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 For compatibility with splitters with borders under jQuery 1.8, I also had to update the deprecated `$.boxModel` to `jQuery.support.boxModel` in 2 places.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem.  I replaced all of the

```
!$browser.msie
```

in conditionals to

```
browser_resize()
```

and then defined a new function just after the header comments:

```
function browser_resize()
{
   if (!$.browser.msie)
      return true;
   if (parseInt($.browser.version)<9)
      return false;
   return true;
}
```