# jQuery Splitter Plugin - nested splitter wont dock

Tags: jquery, plugins, splitter

I'm using the splitter plugin from http://methvin.com/splitter/ and I have 3 columns - of which, the right column needs to be dock-able.  Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tBvp/11/. The columns resize fine, but the right column wont dock!

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Be sure to use version 1.6 or higher. I couldn't find an official repository so I grabbed it from the file linked on the [docking demo](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter-docking.html). Note that I had to fix a couple bugs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321284/fix-for-jquery-splitter-in-ie9/10505994#10505994).