# Jquery splitter plugin getting error too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this jquery splitter plugin located here: http://methvin.com/splitter/

It is working fine with the version of jquery I am using until I enable the resizeToWidth property then it is giving me the error: too much recursion.

Here is a link to a demo I created on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S97rv/4/

Iv looked at the plugin code but im not a javascript expert and don't want to mess with it to much.

Can anybody see a solution to this error?

Here is the plugin code but probably better just looking at the jsfiddle link:

```
 ;(function($){

 $.fn.splitter = function(args){
args = args || {};
return this.each(function() {
    var zombie;     // left-behind splitbar for outline resizes
    function startSplitMouse(evt) {
        if ( opts.outline )
            zombie = zombie || bar.clone(false).insertAfter(A);
        panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "none");   // Safari selects A/B text on a move
        bar.addClass(opts.activeClass);
        A._posSplit = A[0][opts.pxSplit] - evt[opts.eventPos];
        $(document)
            .bind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
            .bind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
    }
    function doSplitMouse(evt) {
        var newPos = A._posSplit+evt[opts.eventPos];
        if ( opts.outline ) {
            newPos = Math.max(0, Math.min(newPos, splitter._DA - bar._DA));
            bar.css(opts.origin, newPos);
        } else 
            resplit(newPos);
    }
    function endSplitMouse(evt) {
        bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass);
        var newPos = A._posSplit+evt[opts.eventPos];
        if ( opts.outline ) {
            zombie.remove(); zombie = null;
            resplit(newPos);
        }
        panes.css("-webkit-user-select", "text");   // let Safari select text again
        $(document)
            .unbind("mousemove", doSplitMouse)
            .unbind("mouseup", endSplitMouse);
    }
    function resplit(newPos) {
        // Constrain new splitbar position to fit pane size limits
        newPos = Math.max(A._min, splitter._DA - B._max, 
                Math.min(newPos, A._max, splitter._DA - bar._DA - B._min));
        // Resize/position the two panes
        bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];     // bar size may change during dock
        bar.css(opts.origin, newPos).css(opts.fixed, splitter._DF);
        A.css(opts.origin, 0).css(opts.split, newPos).css(opts.fixed,  splitter._DF);
        B.css(opts.origin, newPos+bar._DA)
            .css(opts.split, splitter._DA-bar._DA-newPos).css(opts.fixed,  splitter._DF);
        // IE fires resize for us; all others pay cash
        if ( !$.browser.msie )
            panes.trigger("resize");
    }
    function dimSum(jq, dims) {
        // Opera returns -1 for missing min/max width, turn into 0
        var sum = 0;
        for ( var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++ )
            sum += Math.max(parseInt(jq.css(arguments[i])) || 0, 0);
        return sum;
    }

    // Determine settings based on incoming opts, element classes, and defaults
    var vh = (args.splitHorizontal? 'h' : args.splitVertical? 'v' : args.type) || 'v';
    var opts = $.extend({
        activeClass: 'active',  // class name for active splitter
        pxPerKey: 8,            // splitter px moved per keypress
        tabIndex: 0,            // tab order indicator
        accessKey: ''           // accessKey for splitbar
    },{
        v: {                    // Vertical splitters:
            keyLeft: 39, keyRight: 37, cursor: "e-resize",
            splitbarClass: "vsplitbar", outlineClass: "voutline",
            type: 'v', eventPos: "pageX", origin: "left",
            split: "width",  pxSplit: "offsetWidth",  side1: "Left", side2: "Right",
            fixed: "height", pxFixed: "offsetHeight", side3: "Top",  side4: "Bottom"
        },
        h: {                    // Horizontal splitters:
            keyTop: 40, keyBottom: 38,  cursor: "n-resize",
            splitbarClass: "hsplitbar", outlineClass: "houtline",
            type: 'h', eventPos: "pageY", origin: "top",
            split: "height", pxSplit: "offsetHeight", side1: "Top",  side2: "Bottom",
            fixed: "width",  pxFixed: "offsetWidth",  side3: "Left", side4: "Right"
        }
    }[vh], args);

    // Create jQuery object closures for splitter and both panes
    var splitter = $(this).css({position: "relative"});
    var panes = $(">*", splitter[0]).css({
        position: "absolute",           // positioned inside splitter container
        "z-index": "1",                 // splitbar is positioned above
        "-moz-outline-style": "none"    // don't show dotted outline
    });
    var A = $(panes[0]);        // left  or top
    var B = $(panes[1]);        // right or bottom

    // Focuser element, provides keyboard support; title is shown by Opera accessKeys
    var focuser = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>')
        .attr({accessKey: opts.accessKey, tabIndex: opts.tabIndex, title: opts.splitbarClass})
        .bind($.browser.opera?"click":"focus", function(){ this.focus(); bar.addClass(opts.activeClass) })
        .bind("keydown", function(e){
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            var dir = key==opts["key"+opts.side1]? 1 : key==opts["key"+opts.side2]? -1 : 0;
            if ( dir )
                resplit(A[0][opts.pxSplit]+dir*opts.pxPerKey, false);
        })
        .bind("blur", function(){ bar.removeClass(opts.activeClass) });

    // Splitbar element, can be already in the doc or we create one
    var bar = $(panes[2] || '<div></div>')
        .insertAfter(A).css("z-index", "100").append(focuser)
        .attr({"class": opts.splitbarClass, unselectable: "on"})
        .css({position: "absolute", "user-select": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none",
            "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none"})
        .bind("mousedown", startSplitMouse);
    // Use our cursor unless the style specifies a non-default cursor
    if ( /^(auto|default|)$/.test(bar.css("cursor")) )
        bar.css("cursor", opts.cursor);

    // Cache several dimensions for speed, rather than re-querying constantly
    bar._DA = bar[0][opts.pxSplit];
    splitter._PBF = $.boxModel? dimSum(splitter, "border"+opts.side3+"Width", "border"+opts.side4+"Width") : 0;
    splitter._PBA = $.boxModel? dimSum(splitter, "border"+opts.side1+"Width", "border"+opts.side2+"Width") : 0;
    A._pane = opts.side1;
    B._pane = opts.side2;
    $.each([A,B], function(){
        this._min = opts["min"+this._pane] || dimSum(this, "min-"+opts.split);
        this._max = opts["max"+this._pane] || dimSum(this, "max-"+opts.split) || 9999;
        this._init = opts["size"+this._pane]===true ?
            parseInt($.curCSS(this[0],opts.split)) : opts["size"+this._pane];
    });

    // Determine initial position, get from cookie if specified
    var initPos = A._init;
    if ( !isNaN(B._init) )  // recalc initial B size as an offset from the top or left side
        initPos = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - B._init - bar._DA;
    if ( opts.cookie ) {
        if ( !$.cookie )
            alert('jQuery.splitter(): jQuery cookie plugin required');
        var ckpos = parseInt($.cookie(opts.cookie));
        if ( !isNaN(ckpos) )
            initPos = ckpos;
        $(window).bind("unload", function(){
            var state = String(bar.css(opts.origin));   // current location of splitbar
            $.cookie(opts.cookie, state, {expires: opts.cookieExpires || 365, 
                path: opts.cookiePath || document.location.pathname});
        });
    }
    if ( isNaN(initPos) )   // King Solomon's algorithm
        initPos = Math.round((splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA - bar._DA)/2);

    // Resize event propagation and splitter sizing
    if ( opts.anchorToWindow ) {
        // Account for margin or border on the splitter container and enforce min height
        splitter._hadjust = dimSum(splitter, "borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "marginBottom");
        splitter._hmin = Math.max(dimSum(splitter, "minHeight"), 20);
        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            var top = splitter.offset().top;
            var wh = $(window).height();
            splitter.css("height", Math.max(wh-top-splitter._hadjust, splitter._hmin)+"px");
            if ( !$.browser.msie ) splitter.trigger("resize");
        }).trigger("resize");
    }
    else if ( opts.resizeToWidth && !$.browser.msie )
        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            splitter.trigger("resize"); 
        });

    // Resize event handler; triggered immediately to set initial position
    splitter.bind("resize", function(e, size){
        // Custom events bubble in jQuery 1.3; don't get into a Yo Dawg
        if ( e.target != this ) return;
        // Determine new width/height of splitter container
        splitter._DF = splitter[0][opts.pxFixed] - splitter._PBF;
        splitter._DA = splitter[0][opts.pxSplit] - splitter._PBA;
        // Bail if splitter isn't visible or content isn't there yet
        if ( splitter._DF <= 0 || splitter._DA <= 0 ) return;
        // Re-divvy the adjustable dimension; maintain size of the preferred pane
        resplit(!isNaN(size)? size : (!(opts.sizeRight||opts.sizeBottom)? A[0][opts.pxSplit] :
            splitter._DA-B[0][opts.pxSplit]-bar._DA));
    }).trigger("resize" , [initPos]);
});
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is also errors using this script with the latest version of jquery. $.browser is depreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097458/splitter-js-wont-work-with-new-versions-of-jquery Your jsfiddle stops throwing errors when using jQuery 1.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/S97rv/6/

Comment: Thanks that lead me to find useful info

Answer (score 5):

The plugin you are using is based on a old jQuery version. For some reason, an infinite recursion was introduced by jQuery 1.6, probably due to event bubbling. It seems like a `resize` event triggered on a specific DOM element follow the event propagation path, all the way to `document`.

In the resize event handler, you can add a test to prevent recursion:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function (e) {
  if (e.target === window) { splitter.trigger('resize'); }
});
```

That works, at least in Chrome and Firefox.

Using [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) will allow you to use jQuery 1.9 and even 2.0; but relying on browser specific behavior is generally a bad practice. You may have a look at [this splitter.js fork](https://github.com/cmorse/jquery-splitter), which already fixes your *infinite recursion* issue, using the same test as above.

Comment: Thanks, actually I found this fork that fixes it also https://github.com/e1ven/jQuery-Splitter.

Comment: On side note the original author says this in the docs :The other alternative is to pass one of leftDock, rightDock, topDock, bottomDock as a string, which specifies the default docking side. Anybody know how you would call this lefe and right dock I can see no way how to do it.